# You need to enable JavaScript to run this app when configure proxy

Tags: reactjs, proxy

I using http-proxy-middleware to configure proxy for my react app. Everything is ok if I run my app in localhost. But when I deploy to heroku, netlify or firebase, my app have an error message "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app".
My code configure proxy in react app:

```
module.exports = app => {
  app.use(
    "/pool/.json",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "https:myapi/api",
      changeOrigin: true
    })
  );
};
```

My app only have that error message when I call this api.

I tried add proxy to package.json but still not working.

**Note**: I don't use expressJS for my server, my backend is available.

Sorry my english is pretty bad.